# find elements > get attribute > append to cousin

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

```
<div class="links">
    <ul>
       <li class="pdf"></li>
       <li class="weiter"><a href="48">more</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For each LI.weiter, I want to grab the link add sth and append it as PDF-Link:

```
var LinkMarkup = '<a href="';
$('.weiter A').each(function() { 
   LinkMarkup += $(this).attr('href') + '&type=999" target="_blank">PDF</a>';  
   $(this).closest('.pdf').append($(LinkMarkup)); 
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, the anchor is a child of the `li`, to you can use `find`. The `.pdf` is actually a sibling, but is also the previous element, so use `.prev`. You also need to build the actual `a` element and append:

```
$('.weiter').each(function() { 
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr('href') + "&type=999",
        link = "<a href='" + href + "' target=_blank>PDF</a>";

    $(this).prev('.pdf').append(link); 
});
```

Comment: @Teemu -- Yeah - I'm realizing this is a poor answer, give me a min to edit.